# Flash Variables are not accessible in Chrome when Javascript is turned off

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

It appears that the `flash variables are not accessible in Chrome when Javascript is turned off`. Having said that, Youtube seem to work fine, when I test other sites like www.nhs.uk it does not seem to work, nor does mine.

I am using the most recent version of Chrome on Windows. Is there anything special that I need to target Chrome, how do I resolve this issue ?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you saying that your SWF movie doesn't have access to flashvars?

Comment: Yes, If you try browsing www.nhs.uk none of the video gets played when JS is disabled in chrome.

Comment: Why would it play if js is disabled? - doing a 'view source' shows that you're using swfobject, a js library to embed swf's. If there's no js, there's no swf being embedded.

Comment: RaM flash does not depend on javascript by default. You can put an `<embed>` or `<object>` tag into a page with the correct parameters and flash will play just fine. There are lots of awesome tools which use javascript to embed flash movies (which is what most smart people do), but again javascript is not a requirement for flash to play.

Comment: @jpea We are not using js library in all the pages to load swf file, anyway if you did try creating a dummy page on your local machine and try it for your self, you'll know that flash does not work when JS is turned off in chrome. I have tested it and my code has been reviewed by 3 other pll so I doubt if I could have done some mistake!!

Comment: @jessegavin Thank you for the comment but I am afraid I have tested it with the embed tag, and I got my code reviewed by the Front end architect at my work place and for some reason in Chrome, when JS is disabled it does not work, Could you please very quicky mock up a dummy page on your local machine and please try it for your self.

Comment: I did - I go into the pref's and check "Do not allow any site to run JavaScript", then go to the page I made with object/embed and it works fine. Chrome on the Mac. So yes, perhaps it doesn't work in your particular scenario, but it works on mine. Just wondering how often a scenario would ever come up where JS would be disabled, but the user would want to allow for Flash to be shown. Not to be disrespectful, but never.

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome on Windows 7 with js disabled and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your embed code? Are you putting your flashvars on the SWF url or as a parameter in the embed/object tag? If the latter, I think the former might work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pass flashvars to a flash movie. One is via javascript in which you pass a flashvars object. (This is the one that is breaking for you.)

The other, is to add them to the URL path of your swf like so:
`<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE= "movie.swf?text=hello">`

This example will create a variable called "text" in the root.loaderInfo.parameters with a value of "hello"